# How do you add a comment box in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments, shortcut, box

I am working on a project in java for class and I need to add a comment box above each of my methods explaining what each method does. It's supposed to look like this:

*****   *** ** ** ** (asterisk line) *************************************************************************
*@param

*

****  *** ** ** ** **(another line) *********************************************************************

I am using eclipse and I know there is a shortcut that makes this box but I can't seem to remember it or find it on the web...

Comment: did you need like this? type /* and press enter

Comment: you have to use your specific comment template by configuring it on eclipse

Comment: Alt+Shift+j  you can use this to create java doc

Comment: no not the /* shortcut I know theres a shortcut that makes the full box like this with the @param already in it =\

Comment: @CodyTimmer that's what m saying that its predefined custom template created by your company (XML file) configured in eclipse you need to remember on which name the template is stored and use it that name following control+space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto eclipse > windows > preference > java > templates

click `NEW` now give name for your pattern and add description and provide below pattern

```
/*****************************************************************************************
* ${cursor}This is default description for this method. Kindly remove this type the actual 
* usage and other relevant information for the method as description.
* @since    ${date}
* @param    paramName   Parameter description 
* @return   <Description of return value. Remove this tab for return type     void.>
* @throws   ExceptionClass  Description of the exception reason or  scenario
*****************************************************************************************/

/*
* Author    ${user}
* Version   <Enter the version of the product/project for this method.> 
* History   Updated By      Update Date     Update Reason
*           ==============  ===========     ================================================
*/
```

use context as `java` and now final show down create any class and than add method before introducing a method just start typing the name of the above template and than press CTRL+SPACE and select your template and boom your method is read for description.

Answer (score 0):

In main menu Window -> Preferences
In the tree on the left
Java->Code style->CodeTemplates
On the right panel select Comments - >Methods and print the pattern in the right bottom text area

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use JavaDoc to document each of your methods and explain what they do, their parameters, what they return, and any exception it may throw.

```
/**
 * This is proper JavaDoc notation. It starts with a forward slash, two asterisks
 * and then an asterisk per line. When it ends, we use the combo asterisk forward slash
 */
```

When identifying parameters and return types, use the `@` character:

```
/**
 * method add2 takes an integer and adds
 * 2 to it. It then returns the new integer
 *
 * @param someInt    the integer we will add 2 to
 * @return integer   the new integer after 2 was added
 */
public int add2(int someInt) {
    int integer = someInt + 2;
    return integer;
}
```